# Emacs 23.1 make error 139 in Mac OS X 10.6.3

Tags: macos, emacs, makefile

When I try to compile GNU Emacs 23.1 on my machine with Mac OS X 10.6.3 I repeatedly get the following ending:

```
Directories: /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/. /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./calc /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./calendar /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./emacs-lisp /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./emulation /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./erc /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./eshell /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./gnus /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./international /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./language /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./mail /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./mh-e /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./net /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./nxml /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./org /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./play /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./progmodes /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./textmodes /src/emacs-23.1/lisp/./url
/bin/sh: line 1: 69491 Segmentation fault      EMACSLOADPATH=/src/emacs-23.1/lisp LC_ALL=C ../src/bootstrap-emacs -batch --no-site-file --multibyte -l autoload --eval '(setq generated-autoload-file "/src/emacs-23.1/lisp/loaddefs.el")' -f batch-update-autoloads $wins
make[2]: *** [autoloads] Error 139
make[1]: *** [/src/emacs-23.1/src/../lisp/loaddefs.el] Error 2
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

Does anyone know what this means and what I could do to resolve the issue?

By the way, here is my ./configure settings:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --x-includes=/usr/X11/include --x-libraries=/usr/X11/lib --with-x
```

I've tried to compile both with and without X with no success.

Comment: You do know what emacs is already installed on Mac OS X, right ?

Comment: @Paul only the terminal version. If you use Emacs and have never tried the version with a native GUI, you should give it a spin. It is also packaged as "Carbon Emacs". A version with more modifications to make it feel like a Mac application is named "Aquamacs Emacs".

Comment: carbon emacs is deprecated. also if you want to learn emacs stay away from aquaemacs they mess up alot of stuff for os x compatibility. if you learn emacs keybindings they work on all os's emacs support.

Comment: how/when is carbon emacs depreciated? there is a build from january 2010. it runs great for me on 10.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the 23.1 release version does not build on 10.6; you need to checkout a development version.  See [here](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/20936) and [here](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/aqua/emacs-app-devel/Portfile).  You could also save yourself trouble by  letting [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php) do the work for you:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install emacs-app-devel
```

Works for me on 10.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

for standalone version,

```
./configure --with-ns
make
make install
```

compiles fine.

Comment: Now I get this when I configure with ns:

nsterm.m:5219: warning: class 'EmacsView' does not implement the 'NSWindowDelegate' protocol
make[1]: *** [nsterm.o] Error 1
make: *** [src] Error 2

Any more suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I am using the latest CVS version 23.1.90.2 built couple of weeks ago.  
I would suggest checking out the latest version.